# click event on anchor not firing

Tags: jquery, anchor

I'm working on my first jquery plugin. It's just a simple carousel of buttons. 
[image]
It has previous and next anchors. It's the click events for the previous and next anchors that aren't firing.  All the elements of the plugin are generated dynamically by the jquery script.  The only html required is: <div id="carousel"></div> inside the body tags.

Script:

```
(function ( $ ) {

//create the array of days
var day_names = new Array("SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT");
//The number of days in any given month.
var days_in_month = 0;
//the day of the month the first day lands on. In reference to the index of day_names array.
var starting_day = 0;
//Keep track if div.slides already has been loaded or not.
var loaded = false; 

$.fn.button_carousel = function(number_of_days, startingday){
  console.debug("initializing button carousel");
  days_in_month = number_of_days;
  starting_day = startingday;
  //Create initial carousel interface
  var container = $('div#carousel');
  container.append('<div id="nav_previous"><a href="#" id="prev"></a></div><div id="slides"><ul></ul></div><div id="nav_next"><a href="#" id="next"></a></div>');
  //populate unordered list with input type button elements.
  populate_carousel(number_of_days, startingday);     
  return this;    
};

$('div#carousel').on('click', 'a#prev', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.debug("prev click");
});

$('div#carousel').on('click', 'a#next', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.debug("next click");
});

function populate_carousel(number_of_days, startingday ) {
    days_in_month = number_of_days;
    starting_day = startingday;
    var index = starting_day;
    //alert("populating");
    if(loaded === false)
    {
      //first time loading input elements
      var container = $('div#slides ul');

      for(var i = 1; i < days_in_month; i++)
      {
        container.append('<li><input type="button" id="' + i + '" class="btn" value="' + day_names[index] + " " + i + '"></li>');
        if(index < 6)
           index++;
        else
           index = 0; //reset           
      }

      loaded = true;
    }
    else
    {
      var index = starting_day;
      //NOT the first time loading input elements
      var container = $('div#slides ul');
      //remove all the buttons
      container.remove('.btn');
      //then repopulate them
      for(var i = 1; i < days_in_month; i++)
      {
        container.append('<li><input type="button" id="' + i + '" class="btn" value="' + day_names[index] + " " + i + '"></li>');
        if(index < 6)
           index++;
        else
           index = 0; //reset           
      }

      loaded = true;

    }
}   

}( jQuery ));
```

CSS:

```
#carousel {
background-color: #ccffcc;
width:400px;
height:40px;    
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
border:1px solid #ccc;
}

#carousel div{ display: inline-block;}

/* Styling for prev button */
#nav_previous {
padding:0 0 0 0;    
position:absolute;
top:5;
left:5;
width:30px;
height: 30px;   
}

#slides {
overflow:hidden;
/* fix ie overflow issue */
position:absolute;
width:300px;
height:30px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
top:5;
left:47;
background-color: #F5F6CE;
}

/* remove the list styles, width : item width=85 * total items=31 */    
#slides ul {
position:relative;
left:0;
top:0;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;  
width:2635px;           
}

/* width of the item, in this case I put 250x250x gif */
#slides li {
width:85px;
height:30px;    
float:left;
}

/* Styling for next button */
#nav_next {
padding:0 0 0 0;    
position:absolute;
top:5;
left:364;
width:30px;
height: 30px;   
}

#nav_previous a {
display:block; 
width:31px; 
height:32px;
text-indent:-999em; 
outline:0;  
}

#nav_next a {
display:block; 
width:31px; 
height:32px;
text-indent:-999em; 
outline:0;  
}

a#prev {
  background:url(images/left_black_arrow.png) no-repeat; 
}

a#prev:hover {
  background:url(images/left_white_arrow.png) no-repeat;
}

a#next {
  background:url(images/right_black_arrow.png) no-repeat; 
}

a#next:hover {
  background:url(images/right_white_arrow.png) no-repeat;
}

input.btn {
 height:30px;
 width:85pm;
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
}

.clear {clear:both}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Carousel</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="button_carousel.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" carset="utf-8" src="button_carousel.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  //October has 31 days, therefore 31 buttons are required.
  var carousel = new $.fn.button_carousel(31,4);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="carousel"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I have console.debug() statements inside each click event.  Neither one writes to the console.  I don't get it. Why won't they fire?  Please advise.

Comment: It works on my end. It prints the console string.

Comment: do you got in your console? any errors or warnings?

Comment: no errors or warnings.  Just the first statement: "initializing button carousel".  When I click on the previous and next anchors, I get nothing.  Tried this in both IE and Firefox.  Same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ever try using [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) ? If you're working with dynamic element, then you must use this. Example :

```
$('#carousel').on('click', 'a#prev', function() {..});
// or
$('body').on('click', 'a#prev', function() {..});
```

Comment: I didn't know about event delegation.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yeah, come back if got problems

Comment: Ok...I've replaced my earlier functions with: $('div#carousel').on('click', 'a#prev', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); console.debug("prev click"); });  They still aren't firing.

Comment: Opps, it should working. What about this `$('body').on('click', 'a#prev', function() {..});`

Comment: I've edited my initial post so you can see the whole script. I tried 'body' as well.  No effect.

Comment: Hey, check this out: I tried: $(document).on('click', 'a#prev', function(event) {event.preventDefault(); console.debug("prev click"); }); and it worked!  That's just messed up.  Why is that working but not when I select 'div#carousel'?

Comment: Seems like the propagation element narrow up to document itself instead of parent container. Anyway, glad to hear that it worked!

Comment: According to examples I've researched on this subject selecting the parent container should have worked.  So the question remains. Am I doing something wrong?  I really shouldn't have to select document!

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't. Can you post the HTML part

Comment: Yes, I've added the html part.  Hope this sheds some light on the subject.

Comment: Ya, i know what the problem is. Your carousel plugins actually was loaded early during document was reached before it completely ready. All the code inside `$.fn.button_carousel` getting called when the document is ready which is fine, but this `$('div#carousel').on('click', 'a#prev',` was declared outside this function `$.fn.button_carousel` which make all the code inside your plugin except $.fn.button_carousel`  is loaded early before the document is ready. You got what i meant? See modified code here https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/sp7w3bsm/

Comment: Again, `.on('click', 'a#prev',` and `.on('click', 'a#next,` was attached to `div#carousel` at early stage, but `div#carousel` was not loaded yet. Same goes to `a#next` and `a#prev`

Comment: Another example i replicate for you https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/6gun14bb/

Comment: I can now see what's going on.  Thanks for the jsfiddle examples to prove your point.  They really helped to clarify the problem.